# Using outside Python framework (ObsPy) in QGIS API (PyQGIS)

Tags: python, pyqgis, macos, framework

I would like to use ObsPy, a seismology framework for Python available at https://github.com/obspy within the QGIS Python API.

I have been able to use ObsPy to plot moment tensor solutions in an outside Conda environment and upload them as SVGs for point markers, but this is very tedious and I cannot edit the images after. I was hoping to use QGIS Resource Sharing plugin to run the ObsPy repo, but was informed that repositories must follow a predetermined structure.

I am using MacOS Ventura (13.5) and running QGIS Firenze (3.28) which I downloaded via the QGIS MacOS X installer.